# Magnetic Mirrors

Tags: electromagnetism

In magnetic mirrors, it is clear why the particle cannot travel beyond a certain point.

But why the particle reflects back? If it has lost all the kinetic energy along the direction of magnetic field, it should just stay at that point and keep rotating.

Comment: Is it clear? Please provide a reference and some equations.  Then you can perhaps see why a particle reverses: if the force which brings it to a stop is proportional to velocity (or even position), then the particle won't move, but if the force is uniformly directional, it should be obvious that the particle will reverse direction.

Comment: How do particles at rest (WRT some reference frame) begin to move?  Your statement implies that particles with no kinetic energy due to translation will never move again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a spinning particle traveling along the axis of two coaxial current rings? In that case, the force is dependent upon the quantity $\frac{\partial B}{\partial z} $ and losing all the kinetic energy doesn't have any effect on the force. Consider a simple scenario: if you throw a ball upwards, it loses all its kinetic energy when it reaches maximum height. Does that mean the ball is not coming back down? No, since gravity is always there and will pull the ball back down! The force in magnetic mirror is much more complicated, but the idea is the same.